# Collect questions raised by a removed user

Tags: support, search, deleted-users

I have an account which was removed by the system.

I value the questions of that account, whereas I'm not able to search and collect them all.

Is it possible to search all the questions of a removed account?

Comment: So now you choose to give the reason as opposed to just deleting your question like you did when you asked this on Tuesday then? :) Do you remember the user id of the account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the user ID of the deleted account (e.g. via your browser history – the URL of the profile page has the user ID in it), it's possible with a SEDE query. After deletion, the display name is changed to `userxxxxx` where `xxxxx` is the user ID. E.g. [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/763336/posts-by-a-deleted-user?UserName=user6205) will show all posts by user6205.